# Cleaning the stone of a hot-stone grill with a detergent

Tags: cleaning, appliances

The user manual of my current hot-stone grill (Severin brand) reads that the stone may be cleaned under running water only and that no detergent shall be used. However, this way it can't be trully cleaned. Previously with another hot-stone grill (Rotel brand) I used a common detergent and didn't experience any harm to the stone whatsoever.

Is there any particular (scientific) reason why common dishware detergents shall not be used for cleaning of hot-stone grill stone surfaces? Or is just manufacturer looking for some sort of excuses as precautionary matters?

Comment: The stone is likely porous, and so could retain detergent. The next time you cook, the retained detergent could affect the flavor of the food (or worse, infuse the food with dangerous chemicals).

Comment: Stoneware pans, pizza stones, and cast iron skillets are all the same way. The cooking surface is [seasoned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasoning_(cookware)) over time with use, and using soap or detergent to clean them can result in a funny tasting meal and the food sticking to the cook surface immediately afterwards as @Tester101 mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of stone is it?  I suspect it is granite in which case there really is no concern for washing with dish soap.  (Lawyers probably wrote that, so any warrant claims can be denied... :( )

Comment: Yes, looks like granite.